# Read the data version of the current project Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I´m working with Delphi Radstudio 2010. There is under the option **project/options**
a selection **Version information**. When I typed in my information, for example data version, I want to read this information with my current project to use it.

How can I read out the Data Version?

Answer (score 2):

You must use the [GetFileVersionInfoSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647005%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`GetFileVersionInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [VerQueryValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  functions to get the version information. If you only want to get the version number you can use the [`SysUtils.GetFileVersion`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.GetFileVersion) which internally uses these functions.

Answer (score 0):

At runtime you can read the version with the function `GetFileVersionInfo()`. I would read the version independent of localization (pass '\' as the second parameter to `VerQueryValue()`). Have a look at this example: [Version of the application](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/delphi/delphi.html#AppVersion).